# Compute in a lock free manner

Tags: java, synchronization, lock-free

I am writing a class to calculate average of prices. We use it to generate buy/sell signal for some financial instruments therefore latency is crucial.  Prices are sent via different threads therefore class needs to be thread-safe.

Below is my current solution. Am I correct in understanding that I have to use a lock to make the two operations (adding and incrementing) atomic? I have looked at AtomicLong/LongAdder/LongAccumulator but looks like they can only sum the numbers atomically.

In other words, there is no way to do this in a lock-free manner?

Thank you!

```
public final class Computer{

private ReentrantReadWriteLock rwLock;
private ReadLock readLock;
private WriteLock writeLock;

private BigDecimal sum;
private int count;

public AverageCalculatorThreadSafeImplementation2( ){
    this.rwLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    this.readLock = rwLock.readLock();
    this.writeLock = rwLock.writeLock();
    this.sum = new BigDecimal(0);
}

public final void add( double value ){
    writeLock.lock();
    try{
       sum = sum.add( BigDecimal.valueOf(value) );
       ++count;
    }finally{
       writeLock.unlock();
    }
 }

 public final double compute( ){
    readLock.lock();
    try{
        return sum.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(count)).doubleValue();
    }finally{
        readLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "looks like they can only sum the numbers atomically."  Why is that a problem?  You only need to do atomic sums, you can read them freely and then divide.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman Well, I would need two separate AtomicLongs/LongAdders (one for sum, one for count). And there is no way to increment both of them atomically together, right?

Comment: That's true.  Are you using longs, or doubles?  At a glance, I might consider something like [striped](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html) locking, to avoid having only one single lock of granularity.

Comment: Why use locks at all?  Since the add and compute methods seem to be operating independently, then just make the methods themselves synchronized.

Comment: @Ryan I could but using a read lock for compute() has an advantage that it allows multiple threads to call it (if no thread is calling add()). It makes the solution a little more scalable.

Comment: By the way… Why use `BigDecimal` if your inputs arrive as a `double`? The inaccuracy of floating-point technology has already been introduced into your calculation by way of `double`. No point in using `BigDecimal` after that.

Comment: @BasilBourque: That's not necessarily true.  `1e300 + 1.0 == 1e300` with `double` (because the whole `+1` is lost to rounding error.  The 1 being way to the right of the 53 mantissa bits in the huge number).  But an extended-precision representation could use as many significant digits as necessary to compute exactly.  So it totally depends on the use-case whether your need to prevent any *further* rounding error (if there was any).  `double` should be much faster so is preferred if it's acceptable.

Comment: @CaptainHastings  That doesn't make any sense. The way you have it coded, you can synchronize both methods and they'd have the same multi-threaded functionality.  `Compute()` only locks on the `readlock` and `add()` only locks using `writeLock`, You'd simplify your code by synchronizing the method and perhaps adding a `volatile` keyword to `sum`.